# how to check if app is running fine in release mode?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

**check app for release mode**

I want to know that how can we test an ios app in release mode ,and how to check as it is not possible to run release mode ios, app in simulator so how can we check and what are the steps to do that.and i want to do that without uploading to the app store.

Comment: Check this: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/build-modes

Answer (score 0):

For this you can make Adhoc build or App store build and upload it to Testflight to check feature in release environment.